# Can Potential Energy be found by Energy Density?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, potential-energy

I wanted to find a creative solution to the problem:

**Find the electric potential energy of a uniformly charged sphere of radius $R$ possessing a charge $Q$.**

My attempt at a solution:

Consider a gaussian surface, basically a sphere of radius $x$ concentric with the complete charged sphere. Now, by Gauss' Law, $$E(x) \cdot 4 \pi x^{2} = \frac{Qx^{3}}{R^{3}\epsilon_0} \implies E(x) = \frac{Qx}{4 \pi \epsilon_0 R^{3}}$$ Now, let the energy density be represented as $\Omega$. So, $$\Omega(x) = \frac{1}{2} \epsilon_0 E^{2} = \frac{Q^{2}x^{2}}{32 \pi^{2} \epsilon_0 R^{6}}$$ Obviously, $dU = \Omega dV$, and $dV = 4 \pi x^{2} dx$, so $$U = \int_{0}^{U_0}{dU} = \boxed{\frac{Q^{2}}{40 \pi \epsilon_0 R}}$$

The problem is, that is not the same answer as I have checked on Internet. Why is my approach wrong?

**Follow up after reading comments:** Um, I don't understand. How do you go from here to the answer? $$U = \int_{0}^{U_0}{dU} = \frac{Q^2}{8 \pi \epsilon_0 R^6} \int_{\infty}^{R}{x^4 dx} = \frac{Q^{2}}{40 \pi \epsilon_0 R^6}(R^5 - {\infty}^5)$$ 
What after this?

Comment: Hi K.T, please read the help on the [tag:homework-and-exercises] to see that it fully applies to the question you've asked and should not be removed.

Comment: It appears that you are ignoring the field energy stored in the field outside the sphere. The full potential energy of the sphere is to be seen as the field energy of the entirety of the field--not just the field within the sphere.

Comment: I would like to point out that the essence of your "mistake" poses an interesting question in Classical Electrodynamics. Where is the potential energy of a given configuration located? If you find it using the expression $\int{V\rho}d^3\vec{r}$, you need to integrate only over the region of space in which the charge density $\rho(\vec{r})$ is non-zero, i.e., within the sphere in your case. But if you use the expression $\int\frac{1}{2\epsilon_0}E^2d^3\vec{r}$, you need to integrate over all of space. See: http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_08.html

Comment: Even if we do put the limits from $\infty$ to $R$, how does that lead us to the final answer? Doesn't it give Um, I don't understand. How do you go from here to the answer? $$U = \int_{0}^{U_0}{dU} = \frac{Q^2}{8 \pi \epsilon_0 R^6} \int_{\infty}^{R}{x^4 dx} = \frac{Q^{2}}{40 \pi \epsilon_0 R^6}(R^5 - {\infty}^5)$$ 
What do I do after this?

Comment: @KushalT. You need to use, naturally, the energy density at a point while integrating over the (infinitesimal) volume containing that point. In particular, the electric field doesn't go in proportion to $x$ outside the sphere. It goes as $\frac{1}{x^2}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading the comment you have made below, I came to realize that the real deal here is that the electric field is not varying as $x$ outside the sphere.

The problem here is not the integral (I apologize for that as I did not cross-check). In fact, it seems you are not very clear with the concept of energy density.

Energy density is the energy per unit volume. What is important for this question is to realise is that you can use the energy density as a function of $x$ as long as it agrees with the value the electric field would have inside the sphere, and then outside the sphere.

Clearly, as you have derived the E-field is varying directly as $x$ inside. If you apply Gauss' law for a region outside the sphere, you get that the electric field varies as $1/x^2$.

These fields are clearly different in their functional forms. So what you need to do while calculating the potential energy of the sphere is to add the contribution inside and outside the sphere.

i.e. $ U_1 = \int \Omega_1 dV$ having the limits of $x=0$ to $x=R$ (inside the sphere)

And $U_2 = \int \Omega_2 dV$ having the limits of $x=R$ to $x \to \infty$.

The required potential energy will be: $U=U_1 +U_2$. You would find that $U_1$ is having a number factor of 1/40 as you have found already. And $U_2$ would have a factor of 1/8. Add them together and you  get $\frac{3Q^2}{20 \pi \epsilon R}$

Comment: Um, I don't understand. How do you go from here to the answer? $$U = \int_{0}^{U_0}{dU} = \frac{Q^2}{8 \pi \epsilon_0 R^6} \int_{\infty}^{R}{x^4 dx} = \frac{Q^{2}}{40 \pi \epsilon_0 R^6}(R^5 - {\infty}^5)$$ 
What after this?

Comment: I see the mistake I made, energy density cannot be calculated all at once because the energy density inside the sphere is different than the one outside the sphere. So we calculate them separately, find their corresponding potential energies, and now as potential energy is a scalar, we can directly add them to get the final result. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This can be proven.

Potential energy = $\frac{1}{2}\int VdQ$

$dQ=\rho d\tau$ where $d\tau$ is the volume element.

So $PE=\frac{1}{2}\int V\rho  d\tau=\frac{1}{2}\int \epsilon_0V(\nabla \cdot \vec{E}) d\tau=\frac{-\epsilon_0}{2}\int V\nabla^2Vd\tau$

This because by Gauss' Law, $\nabla \cdot \vec{E}=\rho/\epsilon_0$

That $\nabla \times\vec{E}=-\frac{\partial \vec{B}}{\partial t}=0$ in Electro statics implies $\vec{E}=-\nabla V$ for some scalar V.

Now we can invoke a vector identity:

$$V\nabla^2V=\nabla \cdot (V\nabla V)-(\nabla V \cdot \nabla V)$$

So :
$$PE=\frac{-\epsilon_0}{2}\int \nabla \cdot (V\nabla V) d\tau+\frac{\epsilon_0}{2}\int ( \nabla V \cdot \nabla V) d\tau$$

Now by Gauss's Law the first volume integral can be expressed as an area integral over a sphere of infinite radius, but gradient of V is zero infinitely far away. Therefor, the second integral contributes all of the PE.

So $PE=\int \frac{\epsilon_0}{2}E^2 d\tau$

As to why your integrals came out different, they are  very tricky.

You need to remember the factor of 1/2 when integrating for potential energy.

Your limits of integration are different as well. Whereas your limits of integration are 0 to R, R being the radius of the sphere for the potential energy, your energy density integral is over all space. Further, the electric field is proportial to $r$, distance from center of the sphere, within the sphere and $1/r^2$ when integrating the density outside of the sphere.

Sign errors can also be a problem.